# Чи правильно побудовано речення?

Tags: правопис, граматика, семантика

Маю такі речення, чи правильна їх будова та розставлені розділові знаки?

*Нічого схожого, раніше не куштував. Кажуть, що у Японії звідки він і походить, це один із популярних смаків. Дивовижний смак, зеленого чаю Матчу.*

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до сайту Ukrainian Language.SE! Будь ласка, відредагуйте це запитання, щоб обмежити його **однією конкретною проблемою**, з якою ви стикнулися. Якщо ви додасте подробиць, ми зможемо ідентифікувати адекватну відповідь. Уникайте ставити кілька запитань одночасно або запитань, які передбачають **необмежений список** можливих відповідей, які відрізнятимуться лише особистими уподобаннями їхніх авторів та читачів. Цей сайт не є сервісом перевірки граматики (чи, ба більше, стилістики), і кожне запитання і відповіді на нього має бути корисним іншим користувачам, а не лише авторові.

Comment: Мені дуже шкода… Саме для таких запитань, я думав, буде призначено цей сайт. Однак найактивніші учасники спільноти цього сайту вважають по-іншому, тож мені доведеться закрити це питання.

Comment: Потрібно виправити: 1. Замінити слово "вірна" на "правильна". 2. Замінити слово "коштував" на "куштував".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Нічого схожого раніше не коштував.

Зазвичай тут кому не ставлять. Хоча варіант із комою теж може бути правильним, якщо кома поставлена навмисне, для паузи / розділення частин. (Відчуйте різницю між:

1. «Нічого схожого раніше не коштував» — тобто одна висловлена думка: «[Я] нічого схожого [на це] раніше не куштував».
2. «Нічого схожого. Раніше не куштував» — тобто дві висловлені думки: «Нічого схожого [на це не існує]» і «Я [це] раніше не куштувув».

Хоча, якщо Ви мали на увазі саме друге, читач теоретично може не зрозуміти цього й подумати, що Ви просто помилково поставили кому. Тобто в другому випадку, мабуть, краще зовсім переформулювати речення.)

> Кажуть, що у Японії, звідки він і походить, це один із популярних смаків.

Тут «звідки він і походить» має бути виділено комами з обох боків.

> Дивовижний смак зеленого чаю Матчу.

Тут зовсім не розумію, навіщо стояла кома.

Comment: -1: переконаний, що погані (too broad) запитання повинні закриватися, а не отримувати відповіді (також погані). Конкретно ця відповідь має щонайменше один недолік, що вона підтверджує авторську помилку стосовно назви чаю 抹茶, який традиційно транскрибується українською як [*«маття»*](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%82%D1%8F). Викривлення «матчу», НМД, зʼявилося унаслідок сліпого, несвідомого перекладу з московської, де цей чай називається `матча`. Ну, а потім ґуґлоперекладач москв. `матча` {спортивного, родовий відмінок} → укр. `матчу`.

Comment: @bytebuster чому б вам не відредагувати назву чая в запитанні

Comment: @Yola, тому що назва чаю має бути частиною відповіді. Запитання поставлене так, що відповідь передбачає перелік **усіх** недоліків зазначеної фрази. Одним із недоліків є неправильна назва чаю. Саме тому запитання  **має бути закрите** як too broad. А відповідь отримала мінус, бо не згадує назву чаю взагалі. А хтось інший напише відповідь про назву чаю, але забуде про коми навколо підрядного речення. І також отримає свій заслужений мінус.

Comment: @bytebuster, мені здалося, питання питає лише про будову речення (тобто синтаксис) і пунктуацію.

Comment: @Sasha, це було б слушним аргументом, якби було можливо розставити розділові знаки між словами, які нічого не означають.